# Use case instance and Scenario

Tags: uml, terminology, use-case, requirements, scenarios

In the literature, a scenario has sometimes been defined as an instance of a use case.
Do you see any problem with defining a **scenario** as an “**instance of the use case**”?
Please, help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scenarios are not use-case instances and you do not need to reinvent terms:

- The UML specification define **use-cases** and **use-case instances**:

  > A UseCase is a specification of behavior. An instance of a UseCase refers to an **occurrence** of the emergent behavior that conforms to the corresponding UseCase.
- The UML standard does not define the scenario. But **scenario** is a common term in use-case literature, and refer to a general sequence of events.  Mainstream use-case document templates rely heavily on scenarios (e.g. "Main scenario" and "alternative scenario" for variants, error processing or exceptions).

**Usual ATM example**:

- `Withdraw cash` would be a use-case
- `Ms. Smith withdraws cash on October 27 2021 at 9:23AM at the ATM #23782 of Bank Y for an amount of 50€` would be an instance of the use-case, i.e. a specific occurence at a given moment in time with a specific user.
- Following general scenarios could be envisaged for the use-case: use of a bank card to be inserted in the ATM, use of a contactless card,  or ATM swallows the card because of wrong codes.
- The instance may correspond to one of those scenarios.  But a same scenario could happen in many instances.

Comment: I understood. Thank you very much!